# How to control objectionable comments using PHP?

Tags: php, comments, controls

I'm doing administrative control part of my site now, and want to add a feature that would allow administrator to control comments, i.e. foul language. Is that possible to display objectionable comments only for administrative checking? Are there any PHP functions suitable for this?

Comment: what is for `objectionable comments`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a chance of developing a naive profanity filter for a chat widget on cricket.yahoo.com (you can imagine fans cursing each other over chat while match is on, which was quite unacceptable to yahoo reputation).

Idea was pretty simple, provided you have a list of words you want to filter upon. I had a list of about .1M profane words from various spoken languages. Idea was to have a O(1) lookup to check whether a word is profane or not.

Also for catching cases like "fuuuucccckkkk" even though profane word list only contained "fuck", [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) (and related) class of algorithms can be used.This was done by pre-building and caching a specific data structure (in memcache).

Once you receive a comment, following procedure follows:

1. load pre-calculated data structure from memcache
2. perform lookup for each word in the comment
3. lookup for a word (similar words) inside data structure was O(1)

Cached data structure was a mix of soundex, [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) and a few other algorithms